# Different HTML from inline and numbered Markdown links breaks links

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

I'm active in the SPARQL and DBPedia tags, so I have lots of opportunities to link to query results from the [DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql).  If I have a query like the following (in which `&&` appears), the link to the results is the following:

```
select * { ?x rdfs:label ?label . filter ( strlen(?label) = 5 && strlen(?label) = 5 ) } limit 1
```

```
http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+*+%7B+%3Fx+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel+.+filter+%28+strlen%28%3Flabel%29+%3D+5+%26%26+strlen%28%3Flabel%29+%3D+5+%29+%7D+limit+1&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on
```

Using the `[...](...)` link notation, I can make link with that URL that works without a problem. However, if I use the `[...][2] ... [1]: ...` notation that's generated by using <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>, the link doesn't take me to the query results, but rather to a syntax error about unbalanced parentheses.

[bracket-parenthesis link](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+*+%7B+%3Fx+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel+.+filter+%28+strlen%28%3Flabel%29+%3D+5+%26%26+strlen%28%3Flabel%29+%3D+5+%29+%7D+limit+1&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)
[numbered link](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20*%20%7B%20?x%20rdfs:label%20?label%20.%20filter%20%28%20strlen%28?label%29%20=%205%20&&%20strlen%28?label%29%20=%205%20%29%20%7D%20limit%201&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

The generated HTML source is:

```
<p><a href="http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&amp;query=select+%2a+%7B+%3Fx+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel+.+filter+%28+strlen%28%3Flabel%29+%3D+5+%26%26+strlen%28%3Flabel%29+%3D+5+%29+%7D+limit+1&amp;format=text%2Fhtml&amp;timeout=30000&amp;debug=on" rel="nofollow">bracket-parenthesis link</a><br>
<a href="http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&amp;query=select%20%2a%20%7B%20?x%20rdfs%3alabel%20?label%20.%20filter%20%28%20strlen%28?label%29%20=%205%20&amp;&amp;%20strlen%28?label%29%20=%205%20%29%20%7D%20limit%201&amp;format=text/html&amp;timeout=30000&amp;debug=on" rel="nofollow">numbered link</a></p>
```

Pulling the links from there, we can see that the URLs in the HTML source are different:

```
http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&amp;query=select+%2a+%7B+%3Fx+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel+.+filter+%28+strlen%28%3Flabel%29+%3D+5+%26%26+strlen%28%3Flabel%29+%3D+5+%29+%7D+limit+1&amp;format=text%2Fhtml&amp;timeout=30000&amp;debug=on
http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&amp;query=select%20%2a%20%7B%20?x%20rdfs%3alabel%20?label%20.%20filter%20%28%20strlen%28?label%29%20=%205%20&amp;&amp;%20strlen%28?label%29%20=%205%20%29%20%7D%20limit%201&amp;format=text/html&amp;timeout=30000&amp;debug=on
```

Shouldn't they be the same?

### Related, but not the same

- It's not [Markdown produces broken link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126699/225437).
- It doesn't appear to be [Markdown not correctly generating links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95165/225437).
- It's closer to [Links to URLs containing parentheses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13501/225437), which discusses escaping characters, but doesn't seem to be the same, because it doesn't address the differences between inline and numbered links.
- The title of [Markdown editor bug for inline code links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84403/225437) sounds relevant because of "inline", but it's about "inline code" not "inline (vs. numbered) links".

Answer (score 1):

[Fixed](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/detail?r=fcd3765bcd2e12be7c4a982b540f5b14efd8a033) in the next build. To prevent double-encoding when converting the entered URL into a "safe" version, I took the shortcut of just decoding before re-encoding. That usually works, but is really a horrible idea as you have demonstrated here, since what in the original URL would have been a plain `&` and an encoded `&`, i.e. `%26` would end up being the same unencoded `&` in the result.